# Discovering an IP network without dhcp

Tags: networking, ip

Sometimes, actually rather often, when joining arbitrary wifi points on the move, the DHCP server is out of service. However, by trying the usual suspects what the ip range/subnet/gateway of the network is, it's sometimes possible to get connected anyway (of course at the peril of ip collision).

Is there a tool (or even protocol) that makes this guessing easier? That is, some sort of IP network discovery mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is solved on IPv6 by SLAAC (Stateless address autoconfiguration), but I guess you are looking for an IPv4 solution.

Unfortunately SLAAC is not available for IPv4. Microsoft made something similar (APIPA, Automatic Private IP Addressing), but if the router is not configured for these addresses it's useless.

Anyway, your actual problem is, you want to use networks which are badly configured and/or has some malfunction. There is no protocol for that.